# If $a \ge 0$ and $b \ge 0$, then prove that $a \le b \Leftrightarrow a^2 \le b^2 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{a} \le \sqrt{b}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, radicals, factoring

**Assumptions**: Field Axioms and Order Axioms of $\Bbb R$ hold. Also assume that square root of positive real numbers exist.

**Problem**: I know how to prove this:
$$a \lt b \Leftrightarrow a^2 \lt b^2 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{a} \lt \sqrt{b}$$

The equality is tripping me.

Comment: Bingo. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The equality is tripping me"

Then you are thinking too hard

1) $a = b \implies a^2 = b^2$ and $\sqrt a = \sqrt b$.

2) $a^2 = b^2 \implies \sqrt{a^2} = \sqrt{b^2}$ and as positive square roots  are unique, then $a = \sqrt {a^2}$ and $b=\sqrt{b^2}$.

3) $\sqrt{a} = \sqrt{b} \implies a = \sqrt{a}^2 = \sqrt{b}^2 =b$.

That's all.

...or....

2) $a \ne b \implies $ either i) $a < b \implies a^2 < b^2$ and $\sqrt a < \sqrt b$ or ii) $b < a \implies b^2 < a^2$ and $\sqrt b < \sqrt a$.

You've done the heart part, but have gotten tripped up on the utterly trivial.

=====

To be perfectly honest, had someone wrote.  "In the case of $a = b$ the result is obvious." I'd have accepted it.

Or if someone had simply *used* $\le $ signs in the proof (as in $0 \le a; 0 \le b$ so if $a \le b$ then $a*a \le a*b$ and $a*b \le b*b$ and so $a^2 \le a*b \le b^2$) I'd have accepted it without thought.

.... I probably shouldn't.... but I would.

Comment: I was overthinking it. The author made it sound like there's a real mystery to this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because $x\geq y\Leftrightarrow x-y\geq0$ and $$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)=(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(a+b).$$

Answer (score 1):

You in fact already have a proof because if and only if is preserved under negation. You proved 
 $$a < b \Leftrightarrow a^2 < b^2 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b}$$
so that
 $$ \neg(a < b )\Leftrightarrow \neg( a^2 < b^2) \Leftrightarrow \neg(\sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b})$$
which is exactly
$$b \le a \Leftrightarrow b^2 \le a^2 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{b} \le \sqrt{a}.$$

Comment: That's neat. Am I correct in assuming that since $a$ and $b$ are logically indifferent, it doesn't matter which direction the equality is pointing towards? Is there a name for this axiom/property? I'd like to know.

Comment: Correct. You could swap $a$ and $b$ in the next line. The property is sometimes called the *law of trichotomy*. The negation of $a < b$ is $a = b \vee b < a$.

Comment: I know the law of trichotomy. I meant the name of the axiom which allows us to swap $a$ and $b$. I wonder if it's called "Axiom of Indifference". I read it somewhere in predicate logic.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I don't know the name.

Comment: I think Umberto P.  is saying $\lnot (a < b) \iff (b \le a)$.  By dichotomy.  I think Salman Qureshi is say if $a \ne b$ then "without loss of generality" or (wolog) we may assume $a < b$ because it is either $a < b$ or $b < a$ and whatever result we derive will apply if we simply switch the labels of $a$ and $b$.  I'd advise beginners to be cautious of wologs in determining that otherwise $a$ and $b$ and the results *truly* are indifferent.

Answer (score 0):

Both $f(x) = x$, $f(x) = \sqrt(x)$ and $f(x) = x^2$ are all strictly monotonic functions, therefore you can use the definition of strict monotonicity.

$f$ is monotonic in $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ iff

$$
x < y \Leftrightarrow f(x) < f(y)
$$

For all $x,y$ in $A$